# SVG - find fill and stroke attribute and change color

Tags: javascript, html, xml, svg

I have to change the svg color by inline editing (not by css) but here I could not find fill or stroke attribute in this svg code so I didnt understand the where the color comes from and how to update ?

Please check the svg code

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
<title>bird-house</title>
<path d="M12.345,5.215a.5.5,0,0,0-.69,0L2.629,13.829a1,1,0,0,0-.29.919L3.7,21.589A3.011,3.011,0,0,0,6.64,24H17.36A3.013,3.013,0,0,0,20.3,21.586l1.36-6.838a1,1,0,0,0-.29-.919ZM12,12.77A3.232,3.232,0,1,1,8.768,16,3.231,3.231,0,0,1,12,12.77Z"/>
<path d="M2.52,11.6l9.135-8.462a.505.505,0,0,1,.706.016L21.48,11.6a1.486,1.486,0,0,0,1.962.057,1.587,1.587,0,0,0,.159-.138A1.5,1.5,0,0,0,23.52,9.4l-9.1-8.43A3.49,3.49,0,0,0,9.6.956L.48,9.4A1.5,1.5,0,0,0,.4,11.522a1.478,1.478,0,0,0,.173.124A1.486,1.486,0,0,0,2.52,11.6Z"/>
</svg>
```

[See browser view](https://dfd1bkopsl5io.cloudfront.net/Bold/Interface%20Essential/Home/bird-house.svg)

Comment: There is technically no color ([black fill by default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/fill#path)). You may specify `fill` attribute explicitly to get it set to desired value.

Comment: Then how to understand which one is they used , fill or stroke ? @YevgenGorbunkov

Comment: `fill` is fill color, `stroke` is an outline color

Comment: and which one you should use depends on the SVG

Comment: [Just to give you a clue on how does this work..](https://jsfiddle.net/79hp8yt5/)